# Is it still not possible to have div scrollbar style in Gecko(Firefox)?

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I have a requirement to change css from did scrollbars. I know it is possible doing so for IE, Safari, Chrome but as far as I researched for Firefox it was not possible.

I wondering if it is currently available (such a basic studip feature right?) for Firefox without using third party implementation

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of this writing there's no way to use CSS to customize Firefox scrollbars.